# How to set checkbox to default false on page load/submit?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have all the checkboxes on my page to default to false values in order for the API call to take the value as false.

I know I could have hidden checkboxes with false value that are default selected on page load/submit but this doesn't seem to be a very tidy way of doing it. I was wondering if anyone else knows better?

```
function formCheck(){

              var checkBox = document.getElementById('mobKinder');
              if (checkBox.checked == true){
                  document.getElementById("mobkinder") = true;
              }else{
                  document.getElementById("mobKinder") = false;
              }                 
          }
```

I was using this code, however because the API only takes checkboxes with checked inputs. If the box is empty, but not specifically declared false then it will remain blank. I need some way of submitting false values from empty checks.

Comment: Do you accept JQuery?

Comment: Yeah I can do, if its simpler

Comment: Just don't include the checked attribute in the checkbox html

Comment: So you want to set one checkbox (mobkinder) to value of another (mobKinder)? very confusing when you have only one letter different.

Comment: @AvcS — That will send no data at all for the checkbox, and not false.

Comment: @maximelian1986 Sorry that's a typo, I have one checkbox for mobKinder, and if its checked it should submit true value to the API, and if its blank/unchecked it should submit false value. But currently if its empty it submits nothing because API doesn't accept blank values

Comment: @Quentin you send data in "value" attribute and checked status in "checked" attribute. `Element.checked` will return `false` if checked attribute doesn't exist

Comment: @AvcS — So what? When the form submits, no data will be sent from the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Unchecked checkboxes are not successful controls, so don't send values at all.

One hack that is popular with PHP users is to define a hidden input with a different value and the same name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="x" value="false">
<input type="checkbox" name="x" value="true">
```

… but this doesn't submit false OR true, it submits false OR false AND true. This is fine if you use a form parser which discards values with duplicate names, but isn't a safe solution in general.

You could use radio buttons instead of checkboxes as your UI:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="x" value="false"> Off</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="x" value="true"> On</label>
```

… but that involves changing the UI.

You could remove the names from the checkbox entirely and use JavaScript to change the value of a hidden input … but that introduces a dependency on JavaScript.

The good solution is to change the API so it works with checkboxes as they are designed to work in HTML.

Comment: Yeah I was already aware of this sort of solution, but it just seems overly long and wordy for what looks like an easy job. If nothing comes up though, I will have to just do this

Comment: @alfierowett — HTML checkboxes are designed to work in a particular way (which allows you to do some very powerful things). You want them to work in a *completely* different way. That's not so easy.